# How to install Android market?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've created a new android AVD, but there is no android market installed. How can I install android market on emulator?

Comment: that's a violation of term of service. you are asking for something illegal.

Comment: okay, thanks for the informations.. sorry..

Comment: try this http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/11/how-to-install-android-market-in-google.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Market cannot be downloaded/installed independently.

Comment: False! Whether distributing the Android Market application is legal is another discussion, but it is definitely possible to install it in your emulator or on a android device. And I highly doubt that it is illegal to install in your emulator. See my answer for further information.

Comment: try this http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/11/how-to-install-android-market-in-google.html

Answer (score 3):

Google licences the right to distribute the so called gapps, which includes things like Android Market, Google Maps, gmail, navigation and so on. Therefore you only find these applications on devices that have licensed the right to distribute them from Google.

You can however flash the gapps on any device yourself, or on the emulator.

Google for "gapps android" or just "market apk" or the like and you should be able to find either the entire suite of gapps or just the Google Market application.

You should be able to install the AndroidMarket.apk on your emulator, just like any other apk.

Answer (score 1):

We can install android market in our emulator...follow this [link](http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/11/how-to-install-android-market-in-google.html).It will help you